# CSS no longer works after shortening

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I have cleaned up my CSS cause there to be less repetition in but now some of my code no longer works. My HTML is:

```css
.kale-grain-bowls,
.salads,
.burgers-sandwiches,
.sides,
.smoothies-milkshake,
.kids-real-meals {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2.5px;
  position: relative;
}
.kale-grain-bowls {
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
}
.salads {
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
  bottom: 72px;
}
.burgers-sandwiches {
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
  bottom: 144px;
}
.sides {
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
  bottom: 216px;
}
.smoothies-milkshake {
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
  bottom: 288px;
}
.kids-real-meals {
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
  bottom: 360px;
}
.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.video,
.front-promo-1,
.front-promo-2,
.events,
.family-foundation,
.partners,
.fundraisers,
.cousins,
.geniuses,
.greats,
.vision {
  margin: 2.5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.video {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/videoImage.png');
  bottom: 360px;
}
.front-promo-1 {
  height: 147.5px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateMainpage.png');
  bottom: 360px;
}
.front-promo-2 {
  height: 147.5px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/templateMainpage.png');
  bottom: 360px;
}
.events {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitySlideshow.png');
}
.family-foundation {
  height: 149px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/Familyfoundation.png');
  bottom: 75px;
}
.partners {
  height: 149px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/Familyfoundation.png');
  bottom: 75px;
}
.fundraisers {
  height: 149px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/Familyfoundation.png');
  bottom: 125px;
}
.cousins {
  height: 149px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
  bottom: 72px;
}
.geniuses {
  height: 149px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
  bottom: 72px;
}
.greats {
  height: 149px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
  bottom: 72px;
}
.vision {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('../images-source/about.png');
}
.location-data {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.location-image {
  float: left;
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
  height: 300px
}
.location-text {
  float: left;
  bottom: 1px;
}
.foodblock {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 50px;
}
.textblock {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.foodcontent {
  bottom: 500px;
}
.menu-type {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
.spicy-avocado-lime,
.toasted-almond-ginger,
.power-bowl,
.farmstand-tomato-basil,
.chicken-caesar,
.harvest-kale,
.southwestern-chicken,
.watermelon-feta,
.summer-berry-salad,
.cousin-oliver,
.west-side,
.el-guapo,
.adopted-luke,
.buffalo,
.elizel,
.real-fries,
.sweet-potato-fries,
.crisp-veggies,
.side-salad,
.seasonal-special,
.kale-crush,
.acai-berry,
.strawberry-banana,
.lucy-blue,
.seasonal-special-smoothie,
.vanilla,
.chocolate,
.kids-burger,
.grilled-cheese,
.hot-dog,
.kids-smoothie,
.local-apple-bacon-bowl {
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.spicy-avocado-lime {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.toasted-almond-ginger {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.local-apple-bacon-bowl {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.power-bowl {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.farmstand-tomato-basil {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.chicken-caesar {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.harvest-kale {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.southwestern-chicken {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.watermelon-feta {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.summer-berry-salad {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.salad-subtext {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.cousin-oliver {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.west-side {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.el-guapo {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.adopted-luke {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.buffalo {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.elizel {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.burger-top-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.burger-bottom-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.real-fries {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.sweet-potato-fries {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.crisp-veggies {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.side-salad {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.seasonal-special {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.kale-crush {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.acai-berry {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.strawberry-banana {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.lucy-blue {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.seasonal-special-smoothie {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.vanilla {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.chocolate {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.smoothies-top-text {
  width: 100%;
}
.milkshakes-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.kids-burger {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.grilled-cheese {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.hot-dog {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.kids-smoothie {
  background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
}
.kids-real-meal-text {
  width: 100%;
}
.clear-div {
  clear: both;
}
.bgood-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
.mobile-app,
.talk,
.careers,
.press,
.blank,
.fb,
.yt .tw,
.ig,
.orderng-loc {
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: -4px;
  height: auto;
}
.mobile-app {
  background-image: url('../images-source/mobile-app-button.png');
  width: 10%;
}
.talk {
  background-image: url('../images-source/talk-to-us.png');
  width: 10%;
}
.careers {
  background-image: url('../images-source/careers.png');
  width: 10%;
}
.press {
  background-image: url('../images-source/press.png');
  width: 10%;
}
.blank {
  background-image: url('../images-source/blank.png');
  width: 10%;
}
.fb {
  background-image: url('../images-source/fb.png');
  width: 5%;
}
.yt {
  background-image: url('../images-source/yt.png');
  width: 5%;
}
.tw {
  background-image: url('../images-source/tw.png');
  width: 5%;
}
.ig {
  background-image: url('../images-source/ig.png');
  width: 5%;
}
.ordering-loc {
  background-image: url('../images-source/ordering-loc.png');
  width: 10%;
}
/*for mobile phones: */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-m-1 {
    width: 8%;
  }
  .col-m-2 {
    width: 16%;
  }
  .col-m-2-5 {
    width: 21.55%;
  }
  .col-m-3 {
    width: 28%;
  }
  .col-m-4 {
    width: 32.5%;
  }
  .col-m-5 {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .col-m-6 {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .col-m-7 {
    width: 56%;
  }
  .col-m-8 {
    width: 65.7%;
  }
  .col-m-9 {
    width: 72%;
  }
  .col-m-10 {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .col-m-11 {
    width: 88%;
  }
  .col-m-12 {
    width: 96%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /*for mobile desktop: */
  .col-1 {
    width: 8%;
  }
  .col-2-5 {
    width: 21.55%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 28%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 32.5%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 56%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 65.7%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 72%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 88%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 96%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <a href="/menu/kale-grain-bowls">
    <div class="col-m-2 col-2 kale-grain-bowls">Kale & Grain Bowls</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/menu/salads">
    <div class="col-m-2 col-2 salads">Salads</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/menu/burgers-sandwiches">
    <div class="col-m-2 col-2 burgers-sandwiches">Burgers & Sandwiches</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/menu/sides">
    <div class="col-m-2 col-2 sides">Sides</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/menu/smoothies-shakes">
    <div class="col-m-2 col-2 smoothies-milkshake">Smoothies & Milkshakes</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/menu/kids-real-meals">
    <div class="col-m-2 col-2 kids-real-meals">Kid's Real Meals</div>
  </a>
  <div class="menu-type">Smoothies & Shakes</div>
  <div class="smoothies-top-text">SMOOTHIES</div>
  <div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3">
    <a href="smoothies-shakes/kale-crush">
      <div class="kale-crush">KALE CRUSH</div>
    </a>
    <div class="textblock">fresh kale, apple, pineapple, banana, pineapple juice</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3">
    <a href="smoothies-shakes/acai-berry">
      <div class="acai-berry">ACAI BERRY</div>
    </a>
    <div class="textblock">acai, blueberries, pineapple, banana, almond milk, chia, lemon</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3">
    <a href="smoothies-shakes/strawberry-banana">
      <div class="strawberry-banana">STRAWBERRY-BANANA</div>
    </a>
    <div class="textblock">strawberries, bananas, honey, Greek yogurt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3">
    <a href="smoothies-shakes/lucy-blue">
      <div class="lucy-blue">LUCY BLUE</div>
    </a>
    <div class="textblock">blueberries, almond butter, dates, almond milk, lemon, cinnamon</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3">
    <a href="smoothies-shakes/seasonal-special-local-blueberry">
      <div class="seasonal-special-smoothie">SEASONAL SPECIAL: LOCAL BLUEBERRY</div>
    </a>
    <div class="textblock">local blueberries, banana, greek yogurt, basil, honey, dates, lemon</div>
  </div>
  <div class="milkshakes-text">MILKSHAKES
    <br>blended with locally-made ice cream (Toscanini's, Cambridge, MA)</div>
  <div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3">
    <a href="smoothies-shakes/vanilla">
      <div class="vanilla">VANILLA</div>
    </a>
    <div class="textblock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3">
    <a href="smoothies-shakes/chocolate">
      <div class="chocolate">CHOCOLATE</div>
    </a>
    <div class="textblock">(blended with raw cocoa)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My smoothie divs are no longer displaying properly. The lucy-bue div is now floating to the right, and the seasonal-special-smoothie div is now out of place messing up the whole appearance. I have gone back and forth to and from the original code many times and can not find any changes that occur. I'm having a similar issue on another page on the site as well. I am including a screen shot. The text also no longer moves properly when I change my screen size. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUHbu.jpg is a screen shot of the changes, the first and second shot are what it currently looks like, the third and forth are of the site from this morning before many changes to the  site that I would not like to have to revert back to.

Comment: Can you clarify what the correct layout should look like?

Comment: I am sorry if i was not clear. The layout should look like the third and fourth images on imgur, the ones marked as from this morning. I am trying to keep the style change to the text but not where it is currently located.